# Overload binary operator as friend of templated class: Not recognized as friend or linker error

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

There are quite some posts about this topic already, but neither proposed solution did help me to compile and/or link my code.

The general proposed solution to this is to forward declare the class, forward declare the operator/function, declare it as a friend and then implement it.

The code I try to compile is:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"

int main()
{
    using namespace MLL;
    Matrix<int, 4, 4> a({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16});
    a+a;
    return 0;
}
```

## **Variant 1**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace MLL{
    template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX = 256>
    class Matrix;

    template<typename data_t, typename T, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX, std::size_t other_MAX>
    Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_t>() + std::declval<T>()), n_rows, n_cols, std::min(MAX, other_MAX)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_t, n_rows, n_cols, MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, n_rows, n_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs);

    template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX>
    class Matrix{
        static constexpr bool IS_STATIC = n_rows * n_cols <= MAX;
        using container_t = typename std::conditional<IS_STATIC, std::array<data_t, n_rows * n_cols>, std::vector<data_t>>::type;

        container_t m_data_list;

    public:
        Matrix(){
            if constexpr( !IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(data_t default_value){
            if constexpr( IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.fill(default_value);
            }else{
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols, default_value);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(std::initializer_list<data_t>&& value_list){
            std::copy(value_list.begin(), value_list.end(), m_data_list.begin());
        }

        Matrix(Matrix const& other)
        : m_data_list(other.m_data_list){
        }

        Matrix(Matrix&& other) noexcept
        : m_data_list(std::move(other.m_data_list)){
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix const& other){
            m_data_list = other.m_data_list;
            return *this;
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) noexcept{
            m_data_list = std::move(other.m_data_list);
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T, std::size_t other_MAX>
        friend Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_t>() + std::declval<T>()), n_rows, n_cols, std::min(MAX, other_MAX)>
        operator+(Matrix<data_t, n_rows, n_cols, MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, n_rows, n_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs);
    };

    template<typename data_t, typename T, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX, std::size_t other_MAX>
    Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_t>() + std::declval<T>()), n_rows, n_cols, std::min(MAX, other_MAX)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_t, n_rows, n_cols, MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, n_rows, n_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs){
        const std::size_t n = n_rows * n_cols;
        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
            lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];
        }
        return lhs;
    }
}
```

Here the linker complains that the function is not implemented.

```
undefined reference to `MLL::Matrix<decltype (((std::declval<int>)())+((declval<int>)())), 4ull, 4ull, (std::min<unsigned long long>)(256ull, 256ull)> MLL::operator+<int, 256ull>(MLL::Matrix<int, 4ull, 4ull, 256ull> const&, MLL::Matrix<int, 4ull, 4ull, 256ull> const&)'
```

## **Variant 2**

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

namespace MLL{
    template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX = 256>
    class Matrix;

    template<typename data_t, typename T, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX, std::size_t other_MAX>
    Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_t>() + std::declval<T>()), n_rows, n_cols, std::min(MAX, other_MAX)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_t, n_rows, n_cols, MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, n_rows, n_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs);

    template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX>
    class Matrix{
        static constexpr bool IS_STATIC = n_rows * n_cols <= MAX;
        using container_t = typename std::conditional<IS_STATIC, std::array<data_t, n_rows * n_cols>, std::vector<data_t>>::type;

        container_t m_data_list;

    public:
        Matrix(){
            if constexpr( !IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(data_t default_value){
            if constexpr( IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.fill(default_value);
            }else{
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols, default_value);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(std::initializer_list<data_t>&& value_list){
            std::copy(value_list.begin(), value_list.end(), m_data_list.begin());
        }

        Matrix(Matrix const& other)
                : m_data_list(other.m_data_list){
        }

        Matrix(Matrix&& other) noexcept
                : m_data_list(std::move(other.m_data_list)){
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix const& other){
            m_data_list = other.m_data_list;
            return *this;
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) noexcept{
            m_data_list = std::move(other.m_data_list);
            return *this;
        }

        template<typename T, typename U, std::size_t m_rows, std::size_t m_cols, std::size_t this_MAX, std::size_t other_MAX>
        friend Matrix<decltype(std::declval<T>() + std::declval<U>()), m_rows, m_cols, std::min(this_MAX, other_MAX)>
        operator+(Matrix<T, m_rows, m_cols, this_MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, m_rows, m_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs);
    };

    template<typename data_t, typename T, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX, std::size_t other_MAX>
    Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_t>() + std::declval<T>()), n_rows, n_cols, std::min(MAX, other_MAX)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_t, n_rows, n_cols, MAX> const& lhs, Matrix<T, n_rows, n_cols, other_MAX> const& rhs){
        const std::size_t n = n_rows * n_cols;
        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
            lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];
        }
        return lhs;
    }
}
```

**Error 2**

```
C:/Users/CLionProjects/MLL/include/matrix.hpp:68:17: error: 'MLL::Matrix<int, 4, 4>::container_t MLL::Matrix<int, 4, 4>::m_data_list' is private within this context
   68 |             lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];
      |             ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/CLionProjects/MLL/include/matrix.hpp:19:21: note: declared private here
   19 |         container_t m_data_list;
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/CLionProjects/MLL/include/matrix.hpp:68:39: error: 'MLL::Matrix<int, 4, 4>::container_t MLL::Matrix<int, 4, 4>::m_data_list' is private within this context
   68 |             lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];
      |                                   ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
C:/Users/CLionProjects/MLL/include/matrix.hpp:19:21: note: declared private here
   19 |         container_t m_data_list;
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~h
C:/Users/CLionProjects/MLL/include/matrix.hpp:68:32: error: assignment of read-only location 'lhs.MLL::Matrix<int, 4, 4>::m_data_list.std::array<int, 16>::operator[](i)'
   68 |             lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

## Question

I do not want to define it within the friend-declaration.

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong in both cases, and how I can fix it?

Comment: In the first example, the friend declaration is for a different function template. Note in the friend declaration `operator+` has only two template parameter while the implemented `operator+` has 6 template parameters. This explains the undefined reference error.

Comment: @JasonLiam Thanks! And what about version 2?

Comment: Please don't add the solution to your question as variant 3. It makes the answer obsolete and makes the answerer efforts useless as now someone reading the question for the first time will think that the answer was already given in the question. At the most you can instead add a [link](https://godbolt.org/z/PEWE38WGa) saying that the solution doesn't work with gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **problem** with the first snippet is that the friend declaration for the function template `operator+` has only two parameters while the implemented `operator+` has 6 template parameters.  That is, the *friend declaration is for a different function template than the one you implemented*.

Additionally note that you **don't actually need the forward declarations** for both the `Matrix` template as well as the overloaded `operator+`.

In the below modified program, I've removed those forward declarations(but you can have them if you want) and I've highlighted using comments the changes that I've made. In case you do decide to have the forward declaration, make sure that you only provide the default argument `256` only in the forward declaration and not in the definition.

Additionally, for better readibility I've added *postfixed* `OP` after each template parameter of the overloaded `operator+` so that it can easily be separated from template parameters of the enclosing class template.

Moreover, as `lhs` is a const lvalue reference we can't do the assignment `lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i]` using that reference. So in the code below, I've commented out that statement as shown by my comment.

##### Working demo

```
namespace MLL{
//   template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX=256>
//     class Matrix;    //this forward declaration not needed but you can have this if you want and if you do then make sure that you only provide the default arg 256 in declaration and not in definition
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------vvvvvvv---->added this default arg here instead of in forward declaration
    template<typename data_t, std::size_t n_rows, std::size_t n_cols, std::size_t MAX=256>
    class Matrix{
        static constexpr bool IS_STATIC = n_rows * n_cols <= MAX;
        using container_t = typename std::conditional<IS_STATIC, std::array<data_t, n_rows * n_cols>, std::vector<data_t>>::type;

        container_t m_data_list;

    public:
        Matrix(){
            if constexpr( !IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(data_t default_value){
            if constexpr( IS_STATIC ){
                m_data_list.fill(default_value);
            }else{
                m_data_list.resize(n_rows * n_cols, default_value);
            }
        }

        explicit Matrix(std::initializer_list<data_t>&& value_list){
            std::copy(value_list.begin(), value_list.end(), m_data_list.begin());
        }

        Matrix(Matrix const& other)
                : m_data_list(other.m_data_list){
        }

        Matrix(Matrix&& other) noexcept
                : m_data_list(std::move(other.m_data_list)){
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix const& other){
            m_data_list = other.m_data_list;
            return *this;
        }

        Matrix& operator=(Matrix&& other) noexcept{
            m_data_list = std::move(other.m_data_list);
            return *this;
        }

        //renamed all the arguments by prefexing them with OP for better readibility
        template<typename data_tOP, typename TOP, std::size_t n_rowst, std::size_t n_colsOP, std::size_t MAXOP, std::size_t other_MAXOP>
    friend Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_tOP>() + std::declval<TOP>()), n_rowst, n_colsOP, std::min(MAXOP, other_MAXOP)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_tOP, n_rowst, n_colsOP, MAXOP> const& lhs, Matrix<TOP, n_rowst, n_colsOP, other_MAXOP> const& rhs);
    };

     template<typename data_tOP, typename TOP, std::size_t n_rowst, std::size_t n_colsOP, std::size_t MAXOP, std::size_t other_MAXOP>
    Matrix<decltype(std::declval<data_tOP>() + std::declval<TOP>()), n_rowst, n_colsOP, std::min(MAXOP, other_MAXOP)>
    operator+(Matrix<data_tOP, n_rowst, n_colsOP, MAXOP> const& lhs, Matrix<TOP, n_rowst, n_colsOP, other_MAXOP> const& rhs){
         const std::size_t n = n_rowst * n_colsOP;
        for( std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ){
           // lhs.m_data_list[i] += rhs.m_data_list[i];   //can't assing using const lvalue reference
        }
        return lhs;
    }
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEWE38WGa)

Comment: Interestingly enough, I think I had this approach before but couldn't reproduce it for this example. I know it runs online, but on my compiler I'm getting an `ambigious overload`. I'll edit that in the original question.

Comment: @infinitezero Here is the [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PEWE38WGa) that shows that clang and msvc compiles this but gcc rejects this.

Comment: Well that's a shame, since I'm compiling with gcc....

Comment: @infinitezero I am submitting a gcc bug for this so that you won't have to add this in your question. Looks like a gcc bug.

Comment: @infinitezero Here is the reported [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=107461).